# Android : does new intent has "on Resume method"? Can new intent automatically be closed?

Tags: android, android-intent

- This is my second activity that opens contact list
- when contact list is in front and I press the home button
- and I come back to the application
- I want this intent (or Contact list) to be closed
- Is there a way to do that? does it have an onResume-like method ?

public class ContactsGuide  extends Activity
{
    static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 10;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    open();
}

private void open()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/"));
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

1. All activities have `onResume()` method
2. You could terminate the activity in `onPause()` by calling `onBackPressed()`